# Using an AndroidViewBinding (has a recyclerview) inside Jetpack compose's scrollable column makes the column unscrollable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have an android view that has a recyclerview and i want to use it in my compose screen. I used AndroidViewBinding inside a compose column to which i have given a vertical scroll modifier. The problem i am facing is that the column scrolls vertically from the place where the AndroidView is but for the other composables inside the column I can't scroll.

```
Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(
                    rememberScrollState()
                )
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
AndroidViewBinding(factory = MyFragmentBinding::inflate) {
recyclerview.adapter =  ......
}

.
.
.
.
 
// Multiple other compose views inside this column

}
```

I was trying that everything would work properly as Jetpack Compose provides interoperability, but I faced scrolling issues.

Comment: You have to assign Your AndroidViewBinding a fixed height otherwise it will not work as expected

Comment: @ChiragThummar I have tried it, gave fixed height to the AndroidViewBinding using a modifier and gave fixed height to recyclerview but the issue persists

Comment: can you show me the image of what you are trying to ahcieve